# Cloudflare worker for redirect, infinite loop

Tags: javascript, redirect, cloudflare, url-shortener, cloudflare-workers

```js
addEventListener('fetch', event => {
  event.respondWith(handleRequest(event.request))
})

async function handleRequest(request) {
  const url = new URL(request.url)
  var pathname = url.pathname.substring(1, url.pathname.length)
  var response = await fetch('https://eu-central-1.aws.webhooks.mongodb-realm.com/api/client/v2.0/app/1saas-functions-mmlow/service/urlRedirect/incoming_webhook/cloudWorker', {
        headers: {
          "Accept": "application/json",
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify({identifier: pathname}),
      })
      const result = await response.json();
      if(response.destination) {
        return Response.redirect(response.destination, 302);
      } else {
        return Response.redirect("https://1saas.co", 302);
      }
}
```

I want to redirect the user to the response.destination url but it redirects the user to often so it crashes. I think the fetch eventlistener gets triggered when fetching data from mongo, but i cant find a other way to do it
example link: http://lyl.ai/6j6P6Zwr

```js
addEventListener('fetch', event => {
    try{event.respondWith(handleRequest(event.request))} catch(e){console.log(e)}

})


async function handleRequest(request){
    try{
        const url = new URL(request.url)
        var pathname = url.pathname.substring(1, url.pathname.length)
        /*var response = await fetch('https://eu-central-1.aws.webhooks.mongodb-realm.com/api/client/v2.0/app/1saas-functions-mmlow/service/urlRedirect/incoming_webhook/cloudWorker', {
            headers: {
                "Accept": "application/json",
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify({identifier: pathname}),
            })*/
        
        if(true){
            return Response.redirect("https://1saas.co", 302);
        } else {
            return Response.redirect("https://1saas.co", 302);
        }
    }catch(e)
    {console.log(e.message)}
    
        
}
```

second snippet is the current status but still redirecting to many times to destination so redirect fails

Comment: Since the error is occurring in the worker script itself, I would go to the Quick Edit tool (or wrangler if using CLI) and check for any errors there. You can also add console.logs to debug issues - https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/learning/debugging-workers

For QuickEditor (web interface) it'll show errors / logs in the console on the right pane, at bottom.

Just from the code snippet itself, I don't see the function `redirectTest`  (on line 2) defined anywhere. So, could be that is throwing an error.

Comment: i had wrong function in the eventlistener, but i just want to now if there is a way to redirect i get the error that to many redirects happened

Comment: With the function updated, I would guess the issue is related to this line - `response = await response.json();` You may want to try using a new variable here (instead of reusing `response`). I'd also console log the result and make sure you are getting the values you expect.

Comment: i get the value i expect, i think the eventListener gets called every time i fetch in the handleRequest Function and thats causing the error but i dont know how to avoid this problem

Comment: It shouldn't... But can easily test if that's the issue by removing the fetch line and hard coding your response destination value. Your updated code above is still using response variable instead of new `result` btw, not sure if that's what it actually is running?

Comment: i used hardcoded destination and coded out the fetch, and it still redirects to many times.

Comment: I think something may have been cached when you tested? Because for me, your example URL now redirects correctly seems like (http://lyl.ai/6j6P6Zwr)

Comment: i tried it again with the fetch no it does not work anymore

Answer (score 0):

Believe the remaining issue is that the last couple of lines are using `response.destination` instead of `result.destination`. I spun up a new worker with the following, and was able to succesfully test with no path, and with your  path of `6j6P6Zwr` -

```
addEventListener('fetch', event => {
  event.respondWith(handleRequest(event.request))
})

async function handleRequest(request) {
  const url = new URL(request.url)
  var pathname = url.pathname.substring(1, url.pathname.length)
  var response = await fetch('https://eu-central-1.aws.webhooks.mongodb-realm.com/api/client/v2.0/app/1saas-functions-mmlow/service/urlRedirect/incoming_webhook/cloudWorker', {
        headers: {
          "Accept": "application/json",
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify({identifier: pathname}),
      })
      const result = await response.json();
      if(result.destination) {
        return Response.redirect(result.destination, 302);
      } else {
        return Response.redirect("https://1saas.co", 302);
      }
}
```

Try giving this a shot, maybe on a new worker / URL to avoid any possible caching issues?

Comment: thx ill give it a try